# C11: Using `_Generic()` (or something) for types themselves (not instances of types)?

Tags: c, generics, generic-programming

I want to do "[static dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_dispatch)" at compile-time via types.

Specifically, there is a family of functions (parameterized by type), and I want to select a function from that family (at compile-time) based on the type of an argument.

In `C11`, one can do this using `_Generic()`.

For example, the following code works.

```
// gcc generic.c -o generic  &&  ./generic
#include <stdio.h>

void foo_int()   {  printf("%s\n", __func__);  }  // Arbitrary code to show that this works
void foo_float() {  printf("%s\n", __func__);  }  // Arbitrary code to show that this works
void foo_double(){  printf("%s\n", __func__);  }  // Arbitrary code to show that this works

#define foo_api0(VAL)   \
  _Generic(VAL,         \
    int:    foo_int,    \
    float:  foo_float,  \
    double: foo_double  \
  )()

int main(){
  foo_api0(2);
  foo_api0(4.f);
  foo_api0(8.);
}
```

---

However, now suppose that, in the macro `foo_api`,
I don't want to pass **a value of the desired type**,
but I want to pass **the desired type itself**.
(The reasons *why* are not important for the current discussion. Assume such reasons exist.)

For example, instead of

```
  foo_api0(2);
  foo_api0(4.f);
  foo_api0(8.);
```

I want to do

```
  foo_api1(int);
  foo_api1(float);
  foo_api1(double);
```

One can achieve this by using the type itself to create an auxiliary variable (ie. a "witness" of the type):

```
#define foo_api1(TYPE)  ({  \
  TYPE witness;             \
  _Generic(witness,         \
    int:    foo_int,        \
    float:  foo_float,      \
    double: foo_double      \
  )();                      \
})
```

and then both APIs work:

```
int main(){
  foo_api0(2);
  foo_api0(4.f);
  foo_api0(8.);

  foo_api1(int);
  foo_api1(float);
  foo_api1(double);
}
```

---

**My question is:**

Is there a way of doing this **without using such an auxiliary variable**?
(Perhaps there's a macro/keyword in C that can do stuff based on a type itself, rather than on a variable of that type?)

For example, it'd be nice to have something like:

```
#define foo_api1(TYPE)  ({  \
  _Generic(TYPE,            \
    int:    foo_int,        \
    float:  foo_float,      \
    double: foo_double      \
  )();                      \
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to pass the desired type itself.

Form a *compound literal*: `(TYPE){0}`

```
#define foo_api1(TYPE)  \
  _Generic((TYPE){0},   \
    int:    foo_int,    \
    float:  foo_float,  \
    double: foo_double  \
  )()

int main(){
  foo_api1(int);
  foo_api1(float);
  foo_api1(double);
}
```

---

To address [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199132/c11-using-generic-or-something-for-types-themselves-not-instances-of-ty/61199364#comment108265763_61199364) comment:

Form a compound literal as a pointer: (TYPE *){0}

```
#define foo_api2(TYPE)   \
  _Generic((TYPE *){0},         \
    int *:    foo_int,    \
    float *:  foo_float,  \
    double *: foo_double  \
  )()
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but it could be a problem with various types (beyond what the question shows as examples), such as a structure with a nested structure, so the compiler issues a warning to enclose the initializer in braces.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Thanks for the good push for a better solution.

Comment: This is beautiful. I would've never thought of this.

Comment: @étale-cohomology Later thoughts, a simple cast may work.  `_Generic((TYPE *)0 ...`

Comment: Nice idea. Now can you make it work for a type like `int [3)`, where appending `*` is ungrammatical?

Comment: I'll try some ideas later.  Perhaps along the line of `((TYPE)*)`.